# How do I list multiple slugs in Django 2.2 without getting an error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to have a slug in my url for a category, and then a slug behind it for a specific product. Before using  worked when there was only one. Django is confused when I used it twice for 2 different links.

I have tried 
`<slug:slug>/<slug:slug>/` 
and im sure that isn't the right way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names must be unique, such as:

```
path('product/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/', views.product_detail),
```

Then in your view you should use the same variable names.